# Permutation question. 12 seats, 3 nationalities, order is important

Tags: combinatorics

"Four Germans, five Canadians, and three Italians are to be seated in a row of 12 chairs so that those of the same nationality sit together. If the order in which those of the same nationality sit is important, in how many ways can this be done?"

Sorry for formatting. Trying to do nPr format:

(order of the nationalities)*(order of the Germans)*(order of the Canadians)*(Order of the Italians)

3P3 * 4P4 * 5P5 * 3P3 = 103,680

Am I doing this correctly

Comment: Yes you are doing it correctly!

Comment: Yes! you have done a great job!